# Intersection of Three Unique Paths in a Tree

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

For a tree $T$, define $P[u, v]$ to be the subgraph that is the path between $u$ and $v$. Prove that for 3 distinct vertices $u$, $v$, and $w$ in a tree, that $P[u, v] \cap P[u, w] \cap P[v, w]$ consists of a single vertex.

I know that two vertices in a tree can only be connected by one unique path and trees are acyclic.

I believe one of the three points has to be a shared node between all three paths, giving you that vertex. However, I don't really know how to go about proving that or if I'm right in my assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that there are two vertices $a,b$ in the intersection. Then for each of the three paths, one of its endpoints is connected to $a$ without using $b$ and the other is connected to $b$ without using $a$. But that implies that two of $u,v,w$ are connected to the same vertex, say $a$, without using $b$, contradicting the fact that $b$ lies on the unique path connecting them.

Your belief that one of the three vertices has to be shared between all three paths is mistaken; the common vertex can be distinct from all of them and connected to them by three disjoint paths.

Comment: I am not convinced by this answer although It sounds correct. The first flaw in the arguments is that "how about the empty intersection case?". The second flaw is that "where did we use the acyclic assumption: there is only one path joining two points?"!